# Disaster in Madrid!

Tags: lateral-thinking, story, situation

A couple were in a car racing madly through Madrid in the middle of the night. Suddenly the engine juddered, whirred, and died. The broken-down car rolled to a halt, leaving them stranded with nobody else in sight. The husband had to go and get help. He was afraid for his wife left alone in the car, so he rolled up the windows and locked the doors before leaving the car, taking the keys with him.

It took him a long time to find aid, since he was a foreigner in the city and his Spanish wasn't too good. He returned more than half an hour after leaving, to find that disaster had struck! The exterior of the car was in the same state as when he left it, but his wife was dead and there was blood on the floor and a stranger in the car.

What happened?

**Edit for clarity**: all the events that night were down-to-earth and believable. There were no supernatural occurrences, extraterrestrial activity, or anything outside of what is commonly taken to be "the real world".

Comment: This one's been asked many, many times, just not on PSE.

Comment: @mmking, rand al'thor taking a risk for the team by adding one more to the collection!

Comment: Is the stranger dead or alive?

Comment: Some of the answers here are proving to me that we are some messed-up people.

Comment: ...[and man door hand hook car door](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpcOQVEOsR4).

Comment: I've voted to close this question as 'too broad,' as there is nothing preventing any situational answer from being correct. Consequently, it is possible to provide _any_ answer and argue for its plausibility.

Comment: @Emrakul I was very careful with my phrasing so that only the intended answer can be correct. I have been here long enough to be aware of the problem with too-broad lateral-thinking questions! If you check the answers below, I've left a comment on each one except PirateSoul's explaining why it's wrong. I challenge you to find _any_ other plausibly correct answer! PS: you haven't _voted to close_ the question, you've _closed_ it :-)

Comment: @rand Feel free to cast a reopen vote if you disagree, and the question will enter the review queue. I can think of at least a few answers that involve teleportation and/or aliens and/or a very poisonous worm :]

Comment: @Emrakul I've made an edit which hopefully should eliminate any 'silly' answers involving teleportation or aliens or "just stab the oracle instead", and voted to reopen :-)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They were

> On their way to the hospital at high speed because the woman was pregnant and the baby was on his way. Then their car broke down. While the husband was looking for someone to repair their car, the woman died while giving birth to her child (the stranger).

Comment: Nice solution. :c)

Comment: If only we had some form of communication at a distance which was mobile and portable enough to keep on a person...

Comment: @MarkN ...which of course is out of power after checking the x-th Facebook 'best wishes' message on the way... ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Possible answer:

> The stranger went into the *open* car and killed the wife for whatever reason.

Why is this possible?

> "...the husband locked windows and doors *before* leaving the car" - so he had to unlock it again when he left!

Comment: How do you roll up the windows in an open car?

Comment: @randal'thor I see, 'leaving the car' as in 'leaving behind' not as in 'getting out'. English is not my mother language so I see ambiguities where maybe none exist.

Answer (score 7):

PirateSoul's answer seems the most likely. A less-plausible alternative, however:

> It's all well and good rolling up the windows and locking the doors, but that's of no use if you forget to put the roof of your convertible back up!

Comment: This is the one I thought of as well

Comment: Is it even _possible_ to roll up the windows if the roof isn't up?

Comment: @randal'thor Probably depends on the car. Pretty sure I could in the last one I was in

Answer (score 7):

It seems pretty clear to me that

> The wife has been attacked by an alien aboard the spacecraft *Nostromo* shortly before landing. In a rush to get her to a medical laboratory which could remove the alien egg from inside her, the couple's car whirred to a stop. As the husband was going to get help, the alien [burst out of the wife's chest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsD6AL3HJtM), spattering blood across the car's interior, killing the wife, and leaving a strange little alien inside the car.

Comment: thanks for throwing that in a spoiler! i would hate for you to ruin it for everyone by just displaying the real (and obviously intended) answer.  :)

Comment: Of course! I would simply hate to be a spoilsport!

Comment: This is almost the same as PirateSoul's though ...

Comment: Dear god, for the sake of my future wife, I hope not.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this D:

Comment: I also thought of this at first :P @BaileyM

Comment: I haven't DVed, but I thought I made it clear that I was looking at _realistic_ answers. This looks like an example of [this](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1334/the-oracle-was-lying-just-stab-them-instead-and-other-creatively-unh) sort of answer.

Comment: @randal'thor, I don't see a single word you've written which invalidates this answer. I also don't possibly see how this answer fits under the meta article you've linked. I've not only answered your question to the full extent, explaining every detail, but I've certainly not tried to circumvent the problem, either.

Comment: Like the "stab the oracle" answers, this one answers the question under the strictest letter of the law while being against the spirit of the puzzle. I've now edited the OP to make that spirit more explicit (but I still haven't DVed your answer).